# Can we use <li> as a form element in html?

Tags: html, css

Actually, I am using a list in which I am trying use my `<li>` element as a part of form.
I am doing something like as shown bellow :-

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="search-type" value="commercial">
    <ul>
    <li name="search-option" id="buy" value="buy">inputBUY</li>
    <li name="search-option" id="rent" value="rent">RENT/LEASE</li>
    <li name="search-option" id="pg" value="pg">PG</li>
    </ul>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

But when I submit this form there is no appearance of "search-option" in url means I am not getting any value for "search-option" to my php script.

Is there any way to do this without using any `<input >` element.

Comment: you could use only inputs without form, but you need proceed data with ajax

Comment: not correct.. you can style it with anything.. Consult the W3C

Comment: What on earth are you trying to achieve here? li is not a form element. Are you looking for like a checkbox? select menu? what?

Comment: You cannot do like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do so, you need to add an event handler to the li or a parent container, save the item clicked and Ajax the result to the server, or build a form object in memory, or create a URL with the selections.

Here is an example that expects the search to be done on the SAME server as the page is on - I am using jQuery because it is the most convenient for what you are trying to do

I did not wire the Ajax in the live demo.

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/a52v9/)

Suggested HTML

```
<ul id="search-option">
    <li data-option="buy" class="sel">inputBUY</li>
    <li data-option="rent">RENT/LEASE</li>
    <li data-option="pg">PG</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" id="searchLink">Search</a>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Suggested jQuery

```
$(function() { // when page loads
    $("#searchLink").on("click",function(e) { // when link clicked
        e.preventDefault(); // stop the click from any further action
        var option = $("#search-option li.sel").data("option"); // get the selected option
        $.post("search.php",{"option":option},function(data) { // post the option
            $("#result").html(data); // show the result
        });
    });
    $("#search-option li").on("click",function() { // when LI is clicked
        $(this)
         .addClass("sel")
         .siblings().removeClass("sel"); // Swap class
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually, I need post method, I want to create a form in order to search something in database, a type of search engine.

Comment: OFF THE TOPIC QUESTION: how did u add the 'Live Demo' button?

Comment: You will know that when you have a high enough rep to edit the question :)-  all is in here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#html

Answer (score 2):

No, you must use form controls(inputs,select) in order to send data to the server or whatever place you want, not HTML tags

Comment: But in case you were confused on the matter, there's nothing saying you can't use any html elements inside the form tag - except the obvious avoiding of nested form tags. You just can't expect layout elements to be treated as form elements

Comment: "But in case you were confused on the matter, there's nothing saying you can't use any html elements inside the form tag" - you are totally right and I never ment to say that. You could you how many HTML tags inside a form as you want

Comment: I was adding to the answer. Sorry, my comment was for the OP

Answer (score 2):

The short, direct answer is no. However....

Often with this you will find some javascript attatched to the list items. When Clicked the javasctipt will update the hidden form field with the clicked value.

Also note that `value` is not a standard attribute of `li`

Here is an example of how to do this with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)..

Update your html with:

```
<input type="hidden" id="search-type" name="search-type" value="commercial">
<ul id="selType">
   <li name="search-option" id="buy" value="buy">inputBUY</li>
   <li name="search-option" id="rent" value="rent">RENT/LEASE</li>
   <li name="search-option" id="pg" value="pg">PG</li>
</ul>
```

And use the following (you will need jQuery and lean about $(document).ready

```
//Assign the value
$("#selType li").click(function(){
    $("#search-type").val($(this).attr("value"));
});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xcgw4/

You can also use plain javasript but for this demo I'll use the jquery library because it makes life easy.

You would also want to do something to indicate what has been clicked etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use proper form controls. Replace the `li` with a `select` like this:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
 <select name="search-option">
  <option value="buy">BUY</option>
  <option value="rent">RENT/LEASE</option>
  <option value="pg">PG</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

or a `radio` like this:

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
     <input type="purchaseType" name="buy" value="buy">BUY<br>
     <input type="purchaseType" name="rent" value="rent">RENT/LEASE<br>
     <input type="purchaseType" name="pg" value="buy">PG<br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```