# Add FormField to Wtforms FieldList Dynamically With JavaScript

Tags: jquery, python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a Wtforms FieldList made up of FormFields that I want to dynamically append to.

To start out, the FieldList is blank, and it shows up as a `<ul>` tag in the rendered HTML (the HTML here is rendered using an instrumented version of the [render_field macro](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/wtforms/#forms-in-templates) Wtforms uses in examples):

```
<div class=" form-group field-contain  ">

   <label for="listings" class=" col-md-2 control-label">Listings</label>

      <div class="col-md-10">

         <ul class="form-control" id="listings"></ul>

      </div>
</div>
```

I also create a Handlebars template that I use to scrape the input and append it as an `<li>` to the `<ul class="form-control" id="listings">` tag. The data is input correctly, here is the HTML after I've

```
<ul class="form-control" id="listings">
   <li class='form-control' id='listing'>
      <!-- HTML snipped for brevity -->

   </li>
   <li class='form-control' id='listing'>
     <!-- HTML snipped for brevity -- >

   </li>
</ul>
```

(Note the `class='form-control' id='listing'` added to the `<li>` objects were added manually to try to get Wtforms to pick it up)

However, when I do a `print(form.listings)` serverside it gives me the following output:

`<ul id="listings"></ul>`

Does anyone know of any special classes/attributes I need to add to the `<li>` attributes for Wtforms to pick it up serverside? FWIW, if I do a `console.log($(form).serialize())` before the form is submitted, the values in the `<li>`s are in there.

Comment: If the above is not a duplicate, just edit the question explaining what distinguishes your situation and I'll be happy to vote for re-opening :-)

Answer (score 0):

You must use elements like inputs/options/select to get the POST from form.

Take a look at: [Can we use <li> as a form element in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173022/can-we-use-li-as-a-form-element-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that ID's should be unique. see [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really) post. or, simply think how would the function getElementByID work in this case..? Its unclear. **So make ID's unique.**

If necessary, you can add non-unique properties (like name?) without affecting functionality.